# Android: Make list view clickable and dynamic with JSON

Tags: android

I'm having a JSON file which is populated to a listview.First, I'm wondering how to make my list view is clickable and lead to another activity.

The second, I wanna make the list view dynamic. That means, I only need one Activity for the click action on the list I have. And the source of the content (picture,title,description) which is populated to the Activity comes from a JSON file on the web.

For example, I have 13 projects on the list, whenever I click to one of them it goes to ONE activity containing different picture,title,and description depends on the item I click.

I need somebody to improve the codes I provide below.

**Projects.java**

```
public class Projects {

    public String title;
    public String keyword;
    public String description;
    public String smallImageUrl;
    public String bigImageUrl;
    public int cost;

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Title: "+title+ " Keyword: "+keyword+ " Image: "+smallImageUrl;

    }


}
```

**ProjectsAdapter.java**

```
Public class ProjectsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Projects> {

    int resource;
    String response;
    Context context;
    //Initialize adapter
    public ProjectsAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Projects> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.resource=resource;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LinearLayout projectView;
        //Get the current alert object
        Projects pro = getItem(position);

        //Inflate the view
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            projectView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
            String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
            vi.inflate(resource, projectView, true);
        }
        else
        {
            projectView = (LinearLayout) convertView;
        }

        TextView Title =(TextView)projectView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        try {
              ImageView i = (ImageView)projectView.findViewById(R.id.image);
              Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(pro.smallImageUrl).getContent());
              i.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }


        //Assign the appropriate data from our alert object above
        //Image.setImageDrawable(pro.smallImageUrl);
        Title.setText(pro.title);

        return projectView;
    }

}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    //ListView that will hold our items references back to main.xml
    ListView lstTest;
    //Array Adapter that will hold our ArrayList and display the items on the ListView
    ProjectsAdapter arrayAdapter;

    //List that will  host our items and allow us to modify that array adapter
    ArrayList<Projects> prjcts=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //Initialize ListView
        lstTest= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstText);

         //Initialize our ArrayList
        prjcts = new ArrayList<Projects>();
        //Initialize our array adapter notice how it references the listitems.xml layout
        arrayAdapter = new ProjectsAdapter(Main.this, R.layout.listitems,prjcts);

        //Set the above adapter as the adapter of choice for our list
        lstTest.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        //Instantiate the Web Service Class with he URL of the web service not that you must pass
        WebService webService = new WebService("http://pre.spendino.de/test/android/projects.json");

        //Pass the parameters if needed , if not then pass dummy one as follows
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("var", "");

        //Get JSON response from server the "" are where the method name would normally go if needed example
        // webService.webGet("getMoreAllerts", params);
        String response = webService.webGet("", params);

        try
        {
            //Parse Response into our object
            Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Projects>>(){}.getType();

            //JSON expects an list so can't use our ArrayList from the lstart
            List<Projects> lst= new Gson().fromJson(response, collectionType);

            //Now that we have that list lets add it to the ArrayList which will hold our items.
            for(Projects l : lst)
            {
                prjcts.add(l);
            }

            //Since we've modified the arrayList we now need to notify the adapter that
            //its data has changed so that it updates the UI
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }


    }

}
```

**WebService.java** (I don't think we need to edit this one)

```
public class WebService{

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient;
    HttpContext localContext;
    private String ret;

    HttpResponse response1 = null;
    HttpPost httpPost = null;
    HttpGet httpGet = null;
    String webServiceUrl;

    //The serviceName should be the name of the Service you are going to be using.
    public WebService(String serviceName){
        HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();

        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 10000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 10000);
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(myParams);
        localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        webServiceUrl = serviceName;

    }

    //Use this method to do a HttpPost\WebInvoke on a Web Service
    public String webInvoke(String methodName, Map<String, Object> params) {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : params.entrySet()){
            try {
                jsonObject.put(param.getKey(), param.getValue());
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Groshie", "JSONException : "+e);
            }
        }
        return webInvoke(methodName,  jsonObject.toString(), "application/json");
    }

    private String webInvoke(String methodName, String data, String contentType) {
        ret = null;

        httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.RFC_2109);

        httpPost = new HttpPost(webServiceUrl + methodName);
        response1 = null;

        StringEntity tmp = null;       

        //httpPost.setHeader("User-Agent", "SET YOUR USER AGENT STRING HERE");
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept",
"text/html,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5");

        if (contentType != null) {
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
        } else {
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        }

        try {
            tmp = new StringEntity(data,"UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("Groshie", "HttpUtils : UnsupportedEncodingException : "+e);
        }

        httpPost.setEntity(tmp);

        Log.d("Groshie", webServiceUrl + "?" + data);

        try {
            response1 = httpClient.execute(httpPost,localContext);

            if (response1 != null) {
                ret = EntityUtils.toString(response1.getEntity());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Groshie", "HttpUtils: " + e);
        }

        return ret;
    }

    //Use this method to do a HttpGet/WebGet on the web service
    public String webGet(String methodName, Map<String, String> params) {
        String getUrl = webServiceUrl + methodName;

        int i = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> param : params.entrySet())
        {
            if(i == 0){
                getUrl += "?";
            }
            else{
                getUrl += "&";
            }

            try {
                getUrl += param.getKey() + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(param.getValue(),"UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            i++;
        }

        httpGet = new HttpGet(getUrl);
        Log.e("WebGetURL: ",getUrl);

        try {
            response1 = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Groshie:", e.getMessage());
        }

        // we assume that the response body contains the error message
        try {
            ret = EntityUtils.toString(response1.getEntity());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Groshie:", e.getMessage());
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public static JSONObject Object(Object o){
        try {
            return new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(o));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public InputStream getHttpStream(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = null;
        int response = -1;

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
            throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

        try{
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();

            response = httpConn.getResponseCode();                

            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                in = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException("Error connecting");
        } // end try-catch

        return in;
    }

    public void clearCookies() {
        httpClient.getCookieStore().clear();
    }

    public void abort() {
        try {
            if (httpClient != null) {
                System.out.println("Abort.");
                httpPost.abort();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Your App Name Here" + e);
        }
    }


}
```

and here's the JSON file:

```
[{
    "title": "CARE Deutschland-Luxemburg e.V.",
    "keyword": "CARE",
    "description": "<p><b>Das CARE-Komplett-Paket für Menschen in Not</b",
    "smallImageUrl": "http://cdn.spendino.de/web/img/projects/home/1284113658.jpg",
    "bigImageUrl":"http://cdn.spendino.de/web/img/projects/small/1284113658.jpg",
    "cost": "5"
},
{
    "title": "Brot für die Welt",
    "keyword": "BROT",
    "description": "<p>„Brot für die Welt“ unterstützt unter der Maßgabe 'Helfen, wo die Not am größten ist' ausgewählte Projekte weltweit.",
    "smallImageUrl": "http://cdn.spendino.de/web/img/projects/home/1267454286.jpg",
    "bigImageUrl":"http://cdn.spendino.de/web/img/projects/small/1267454286.jpg",
    "cost": "5"
},
{
    "title": "Deutsche AIDS-Stiftung",
    "keyword": "HIV",
    "description": "<p>Die Deutsche AIDS-Stiftung unterstützt mit ihren finanziellen Mitteln seit mehr als 20 Jahren Betroffene, die an HIV und AIDS erkrankt sind.",
    "smallImageUrl": "http://cdn.spendino.de/web/img/projects/home/1258365722.jpg",
    "bigImageUrl":"http://cdn.spendino.de/web/img/projects/small/1258365722.jpg",
    "cost": "5"
}]
```

Screenshot of the list view:
[image]

If something is not clear, please let me know. 
Thank you very much

Comment: how to when click move class??
thanks:D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to implement the click:

```
lstTest.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Projects p = (Projects ) lstTest.getItemAtPosition(position);                   

                //Do your logic and open up a new Activity.
            }
        });
```

Comment: so I added this line after your comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, ProjektADH.class);
             startActivity(intent); but when I click the item, the app crashed. What should I add more? Thx

Comment: Try debugging it :-) It shows that the clickListener is working tho.

Comment: Start with making a toast with the position, then converting it into an object.. and so forth

Comment: do I have to initialize the 'p' again somewhere?

Comment: Whenever you create a new activity, make sure you make its entry in the manifest file!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, JSON isn't gonna do this for you. you'll have to implement your logic.
Consider JSON just as a huge data dump.

Here's how you should go about it:

1. Have the JSON
2. construct a suitable data structure (an Array, ArrayList, whatever you like) to hold crucial data about your list view
3. Use this data structure as the source for your list view
4. when the user clicks on any row, try to find out the position of the row in the list view, and on that position in your source data structure, look for the data needed.
5. create any activity which handles these data generally
6. open that activity with the data of the row which user clicked in step 4
7. Consume this data in your new activity

This way, you can add dynamics to your activity that displays the data according to the row clicked

Comment: I'm having trouble with the logic in doing number 4, can you help me by editing my code? Thx much in advance